# Uploading your database projects on GitHub

Tags: oracle, github

How do you guys upload your database projects to GitHub?

I'm learning Oracle and would like to be more active on Github, but I don't know exactly how to post my projects/studies.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is create a new repository in GitHub through their web site and then clone it on my laptop using the command line version of git. Then I add my files on my laptop and do a git add, git commit, git push series of commands using git to push the committed changes back to GitHub. Here is one of my repositories for example:

```
https://github.com/bobbydurrett/OracleDatabaseTuningSQL
```

It is just a bunch of SQL*Plus scripts. When I update one or add a new one I just do the whole git add, git commit, git push sequence of steps again. I run git from the Windows command prompt.

Bobby